# Unable to convert to java Object using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following JSON , which i need to convert to Java Object

```
[{
    "emp": {
        "name": "pavan"
    },
    "dept": {
        "deptName": "cse"
    }
}]
```

I am trying to convert this JSON to Java Object using GSON Framework

```
public class Root {
    
    private Data data ;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}



public class Data {
    
    private Emp emp;

    private Dept dept;

    public void setEmp(Emp emp){
        this.emp = emp;
    }
    public Emp getEmp(){
        return this.emp;
    }
    public void setDept(Dept dept){
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public Dept getDept(){
        return this.dept;
    }

}



public class Emp
{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}


  public class Dept
{
    private String deptName;

    public void setDeptName(String deptName){
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    public String getDeptName(){
        return this.deptName;
    }
```

This is my Test class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String json = "[{\r\n" + 
                "   \"emp\": {\r\n" + 
                "       \"name\": \"pavan\"\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   \"dept\": {\r\n" + 
                "       \"deptName\": \"cse\"\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}]";
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        
        Root[] root = gson.fromJson(json, Root[].class);
        
        System.out.println(root[0].getData());
        

    }
```

I am using GSON to convert json to Java Object
I am getting null when i do the getData , can anybody please tell me why the conversion is not happening

Comment: The `emp` field needs to be of a type which has a `name` field (of type String) and the `dept` field needs to be of a type which has a `deptName` field also od String. (in this simplistic setting with no annotation etc.)

Comment: there's also no data field, so you might need to do `Data[] root = gson.fromJson(json, Data[].class);`

Answer (score 1):

The Root class is redundant.

Change

```
 Root[] root = gson.fromJson(json, Root[].class);
```

to

```
 Data[] data= gson.fromJson(json, Data[].class);
```